# Does anyone know what Shinichirō Kobayashi and Takashi Kochiyama are doing now?

Tags: anime-production

Shinichirō Kobayashi and Takashi Kochiyama were the founders of [Manglobe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manglobe) which made some pretty awesome anime like Ergo Proxy, Samurai Champloo and Genocidal Organ. Wikipedia does not have anything on them and they haven't been on the news since Manglobe went bankrupt.

Does anybody know what they have been doing? Have they left the anime industry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About **Shinichirō Kobayashi**, he has been working as a 3D animation producer for [Image Logic](https://image-logic.co.jp/) and a creative producer for [Mangrove](https://man-grove.co.jp/).

According to [CGWORLD.jP - 「まずストーリーありき」。
リアルタイムカットシーンで魅せたイメージ・ロジックのディレクターズに聞く、 制作スタイルとは。](https://cgworld.jp/interview/imagelogic-202201.html),

> そんなイメージ・ロジックがゼロから"物語"をクリエイトする心強い味方が、関連会社のマン・グローブだ。クリエイティブ・プロデューサーを務める小林真一郎氏は、アニメオリジナル企画のプロデューサーとして数々の作品を手がけてきた。「…」
>
> ---
>
> Image Logic's reassuring ally in creating "stories" from scratch is its affiliated company, Mangrove. Mr. Shinichiro Kobayashi, a creative producer, has worked on numerous original anime projects as a producer. [...]

According to his profile on [アニメーション学科 講師紹介](https://www.amgakuin.co.jp/contents/p=14893),

> [PROFILE]
> 株式会社イメージ・ロジック／3Dアニメーションプロデューサー、株式会社マン・グローブ／クリエイティブプロデューサー
> 主な企画・プロデュース作品は『勇者王ガオガイガー』シリーズ 『無限のリヴァイアス』『サムライチャンプルー』『デッドマン・ワンダーランド』『ハヤテのごとく！』シリーズなど。
>
> ---
>
> [PROFILE]
> Image Logic Inc. / 3D Animation Producer, Mangrove Inc. / Creative Producer
> Major planning and producing works include "The King of Braves GaoGaiGar" series, "Infinite Ryvius," "Samurai Champloo," "Deadman Wonderland," "Hayate the Combat Butler" series, etc.

---

As for **Takashi Kochiyama**, he has been working as an animation producer for [Asahi Production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asahi_Production), including [*Santa Company: The Secret of Christmas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Company) (2019), [*Heaven's Design Team*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaven%27s_Design_Team) (2021), and [*Giant Beasts of Ars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_Beasts_of_Ars) (2023).

According to [アニメ「天地創造デザイン部」が、釜山映画祭内アジアコンテンツアワードでBest Asian Animationを受賞しました！](https://tendebu.jp/news/detail.php?id=1094943),

> 作品を代表してリモートで受賞式に参加していたのは、本作の監督・増井壮一とアニメーションプロデューサー・河内山隆。「…」
>
> ---
>
> Remotely representing the film at the award ceremony were the film's director, Soichi Masui, and animation producer, Takashi Kochiyama. [...]

The Japanese Wikipedia article about the series ([1](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BB%E3%82%AB%E3%83%B3%E3%83%91%E3%83%8B%E3%83%BC), [2](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A9%E5%9C%B0%E5%89%B5%E9%80%A0%E3%83%87%E3%82%B6%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E9%83%A8#%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%83%E3%83%95), [3](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AE%E5%B7%A8%E7%8D%A3)) also mentions him as the animation producer.